# GCC -Wall displays 'unused parameter' warning when using uin64_t mixed with -m32 and Unity testing framework

Tags: pointers, gcc, warnings, 32bit-64bit

I'm implementing some unit tests (with Unity, in my Linux 64 bits) for a SW whose target platform is a 32 bit machine.

I have added the flag `-m32` for stop getting warnings for 'mixing' 32 and 64 bit pointers. The problem is that now I obtain the warnings:

```
warning: unused variable 
warning: unused parameter
```

And the code in which I obtain this error is

```
static void checker1(uint8_t *addr,
                     uint64_t *data,
                     uint8_t b0,
                     uint8_t b1,
                     uint8_t d)
{
  const uint32_t reg_addr_expec[] = {0};
  const uint64_t reg_data_expec[] = {0xffffffef};

  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_HEX(reg_addr_expec[0], addr[0]);
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_HEX64(reg_data_expec[0], data[0]);
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT(1, b0);
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT(0, b1);
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT(0, d);
}
```

I obtain those warnings only when enabling `-m32`. I have no idea how can this happen. Any idea?

### EDIT

I have observed that I only obtain these warnings with either `uint64_t` values or with `uint32_t` ones, but using `TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_HEX64`. it seems to be related with the type `uint64_t`. Is the problem that `uint64_t` and `-m32` cannot be mixed when using `gcc` (`arm-gcc` doesn't have this problem)?

Comment: I think it'd be useful to know how does `TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_HEX64` is evaluated. Use `gcc -E` option or `cpp` to get how does it look like after preprocessor stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Unity documentation, the support for 64 bit functionality must be enabled manually, unless Unity can detect the 64 bit config automatically.

That was my case before adding the `-m32` flag, but now that I have added it, Unity doesn't enable 64 bit functionality by default.

The problem has been solved by adding the following line to the `gcc` command:

```
-DUNITY_SUPPORT_64
```